# Circular dependencies using definition files

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency

In my project I reference other files using their definition files (.d.ts) instead of the actual file (.ts), and that's since the typescript compiler has the tendency to compile any .ts file in it's path, even when all I want is to compile one file.  Referencing .d.ts files avoids that.

Now, let's say I had a big file and decided to break it into two separate files, but still need each file to use the other. The first file is loaded then loads the other one:

one.ts:

```
/// <reference path="two.d.ts" />
module myModule {
    var data: any;

    export function init(): void {
        // load script two.js
    }

    export function twoLoaded(): void {
        myModule.doSomething(data);
    }
}
```

two.ts:

```
/// <reference path="one.d.ts" />
module myModule {
    export function doSomething(data: any): void {
        // ...
    }

    myModule.twoLoaded();
}
```

When I try to compile one of the files however I get `Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient` error message, but in my read project it's a `Duplicate identifier` error message.

Any idea how I can work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually organize something like this is that you designate one file as the "root file". So let's say you have a main.ts that uses both one.ts and two.ts. The references only need to be included in main.ts and not the other files. In IntelliJ (which is what I use), you mark the file watcher to "compile main files only".

So a good way to set this up is:

main.ts

```
/// <reference path="one.ts" />
/// <reference path="two.ts" />
class Main{
    constructor(){
        new One();
        new Two();
    }
}
new Main();
```

Then remove the references from the other files.

Comment: Well, I have A LOT of files, the example I gave is a simple one to demonstrate the problem. What you're saying is fine under certain circumstances, but in my case those two files have to be different and need to reference each other (it's a requirement I can't bypass)

Comment: If I understand the problem, it's that you have two files that reference the same d.ts file? Can one of the files simply reference the actual ts file? We have a similar setup but I've never run into this problem. Can you post a small project that demonstrates the issue with just a few files?

Comment: Oh, wait, I'm sorry. I guess I understand it now. Both your files are declaring module myModule. But why is that? Shouldn't you be using namespaces in a unique way? There's something off about your general approach which is causing some problems. How can refactor your structure to alleviate the problem?

Comment: There's no problem working on the same namespace, tsc will output `var myModule; (function(myModule) { .... })(myModule || (myModule = {})` so if there's already a definition for `myModule` it will be used and the new exported methods, classes, vars will be just added...

Comment: Can you post some more complete code so we can see the problem?

Comment: ok, i edited my original question, hope this makes more sense

Comment: The code works for me using IntelliJ. I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Well, for me it doesn't, using IntelliJ as well... How does it work for you?

Comment: I can make this work using terminal and simply typing tsc one.ts

Comment: Of course..  You need to have both `.d.ts` files there as well for the errors to kick in.. The problem is that they two have reference to each other, and then you get the circular referencing.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of error can be explained as the difference in the language service vs. Compiler.

The 'Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient' error can be explained with the following

```
declare module foo{}
module foo{}
```

Solution : use external modules with --noResolve compiler flag.

Comment: Where did you come up with that flag? It's undocumented, haven't found a thing on that. But, using it just generates the following error: `The property 'doSomething' does not exist on value of type 'typeof myModule'` Which I can understand if that flag does what I think it does.